# Rails Carrierwave avatar update validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, upload, carrierwave

I'm having kinda strange problem with the avatar uploading, using Carrierwave gem. The avatar is just a column in the user's profile.

If no avatar was uploaded previously - all validations (Presence validation, at least) work as they should.

But, if there is an avatar uploaded, and the user wants to update it (upload new one) - then for some unknown reasons all validations, located in the Profile model are just **skipped**, entirely.

Validations in the mounted uploader (AvatarUploader) are working, though (all the time)

All the code is pretty much default, so, there is even no reason to write it here.

Does anybody know, how to solve this problem ? :(

Comment: After a few dozen of experiments, I found out, that if the file of the avatar is equal to the column value, then this problem is occuring. What the hell ?

Comment: Still no solution to this one. And also, I've noticed that uploader extension validations aren't firing from time to time.